# What is the best way to get the value of what user is logged in?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows form application that users can log into. The application is alone and doesn't connect with anything or anyone.

Besides creating a global variable, how could I have an easily accesible variable to check the current users permissions?

A not so kosher way of doing things is just pass the ID of the userType in the Form constructor and according to that, .Enable = false; buttons they don't have permissions to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the id of the currently logged on Windows user (ie. the user that the application is running as), there are two ways of getting it:

1. By putting `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);` in your startup, you can use [`Thread.CurrentPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx) to get the user's security principal.
2. You can use [`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0.aspx) to get the current user's identity. You can then create a security principal using `new WindowsPrincipal(identity)`.

Both of these are equivalent, and will get you a [security principal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) that has an [IsInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole.aspx) method that can be used to check permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WindowsIdentity class for getting the users Identity, found under System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.

```
WindowsIdentity current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
Console.WriteLine("Name:" + current.Name);
```

Use the WindowsPrincipal class for getting the users Roles, found under System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.

```
WindowsIdentity current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(current);

if (principal.IsInRole("your_role_here")
{
Console.WriteLine("Is a member of your role");
}
```